# how to get only quick start AMIs through AWS describe-images API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

Can we get only the **quick start AMI list** through describe-images api?

How to filter those AMIs then?

Answer (score 0):

[AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/finding-an-ami.html#finding-quick-start-ami) explain how to get the list using AWS CLI.

For example, for Amazon Linux 2:

```
aws ec2 describe-images \
    --owners amazon \
    --filters "Name=name,Values=amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.????????.?-x86_64-gp2" "Name=state,Values=available" \
    --query "reverse(sort_by(Images, &CreationDate))[:1].ImageId" \
    --output text
```

Comment: AWS docs doesn't have any filter for listing quickstart AMI it seems

Comment: @MohammedMuzzamil What do you mean. It gives exact AWS CLI to "To locate the current version of a Quick Start AMI".

Comment: This is not answering the question. OP is asking for a way to retrieve the quick start AMIs (which at the moment of writing this are 47; a few of Ubuntu, a few of MacOS, a few of SUSE, a few of Windows server, a few of Amazon Linux and a few of Debian). Your command will return all of Amazon Linux (a few hundreds).